# Интеграция 1с и php?

Tags: php, 1с

Кто сталкивался, интересует пример ответа 1с, стандартные варианты не подходят, делаю без логина и пароля, пробовал с проверкой

```
session_start();
if(isset($_GET['type']) && $_GET['type'] == 'catalog' && isset($_GET['mode']) && $_GET['mode'] == 'checkauth'){
  print 'success\n';
  print session_name().'\n';
  print session_id().'\n'; }
```

пробовал так

```
$login = 'adm';
        $pass = '123456';
        if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"])) {
         list($_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_USER"], $_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_PW"]) = explode(":", base64_decode(substr($_SERVER["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"], 6)));
        }
            if (!(isset($_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_USER"]) && isset($_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_PW"]))) {
                echo "No authentication credentials";
            }
            if($_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_USER"]===$login && $_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_PW"]===$pass){
            echo session_name()."\n";
            echo session_id()."\n";
            echo "success\n";
            exit;
            }
```

Не соединяет. Сам файл xml давно разобрал, база создана, все четко, но 1с не видит подключения, убирал https и на http пробовал, кто сталкивался подскажите

Comment: Запросы на указанный скрипт приходит от 1С? В логах http-сервера их видите?

Answer (score 1):

Первый вариант не работает потому, что при выводе ответа у строк не интерполируются символы перевода строки - все строки должны быть заключены в двойные кавычки вместо одинарных.

Второй вариант не работает потому, что при выводе ответа, строка со значением `success` не выводится первой.